# jQuery Validation Plugin with jQuery 1.4.3

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

Using the jQuery validation plugin(Ver 1.7) from [here](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/)...breaks when upgrading to version 1.4.3 of jQuery...Does anyone know of an alternate solution or a fix for this issue?

The use of the plugin causes an "Object doesn't support this property or method
" error to be thrown

Comment: Do you REALLY need to upgrade to the version 1.4.3 of jquery? I think it's easier downgrade the jquery instead of looking for another plugin and learning how to use it. ;)

Comment: Well yes...I am using the DataLink plugin which depends on 1.4.3

Comment: @Jayme: This only moves the problem. You'll need to upgrade jQuery some day, anyway.

Comment: Which is the version of validation plugin you are using?

Comment: I am using version 1.7 of the validate plugin...Question Edited to reflect this.

Comment: Have you run your page and css through validation (w3c, not the plugin :))?

Comment: Yep, everything checks out...I did find this issue posted on the jquery forum with no answer either....http://forum.jquery.com/topic/validation-plugin-don-t-work-with-jquery-1-4-3

Comment: Would you mind pasting any custom parameters you're using when you call the plugin? I've been using it successfully even after upgrading to 1.4.3 (now 1.4.4).

Comment: @Grillz Nothing special going on just basic required fields. Calling $('#form').validate()

Comment: Hrm, Are you using the full or minified version? I've heard of problems in ie6 with the packed version of validation. I know you said you are calling everything as normal, but it would be helpful to see all the js you're using in case there is a conflict.

Comment: This is happening in IE8 and firefox...i can try to get some code up asap

Comment: @elusive No, not really. I use the version that works, if the newer give me problems, I get back to the older one ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ended up upgrading to 1.4.4 to fix this...